# Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations in android 6

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem that happen recently on devices with android version 6.0

I am getting the following crash

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1627)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1579)
at ub.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1191)
at to.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:2110)
at lw.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:148)
at ml.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1164)
at nf.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:260)
at na.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:324)
at tn.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:78)
at maps.af.L.a(Unknown Source)
at na.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:13201)
at mo.g(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:499)
at mo.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:435)
at mh.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1437)
at pj.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:227)
at oz.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:780)
at oq.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1829)
at ot.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:5339)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

can anyone help please ?

Comment: added ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in manifest file ?

Comment: did you ask for permission to get that?

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: yes I have added permission to manifest file 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: but did you ask for runtime permission?

Comment: You have to request permission at RunTime if you don't do it already - devices running Android 6.0 and above

Comment: @antonio : targetSdkVersion 15

Comment: @Eenvincible : no I did not add runtime permission, how can I add it ?

Comment: First you should alwauys be targeting the latest sdk version (24 now) and second since you are only targeting sdk 15 you do not need to as for runtime permissions but a user on 6.0 can always disable that permission

Comment: @tyczj so If I use sdk version 24 as my targetSDKVersion the app will stop crashing in android 6 devices ??

Comment: if you target 24 you will have to request permissions at runtime and depending on how you handle those permissions deemed dangerous on android it will stop crashing

Answer (score 4):

Your Android 6 users can revoke the permissions of your application selectively, so you must ask for permissions at runtime.

An example from [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 111;

// ...

// Check for permission
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this, // Activity
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
}

// Get permission result
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted

            } else {
                // permission was denied
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If these permissions are already in AndroidManifest.xml file, Set `targetSdkVersion` to **22** in app level build.gradle file as following...

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1'
    }
}
```

**Note** that runtime permissions are always preferable approach.